# Matching full URL in RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block all POST access to a site (and return a 403), except from 2 IP's and TO one URL (http://mydomain.com/about-us/contact-us/).

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=4.3.2.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://mydomain.com/about-us/contact-us/$
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
```

These rules are allowing access from all IP properly, but the contact page is still not accessible. I'm not sure I'm using the REQUEST_URI correctly?

I've also tried variations with relative URLs like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us/contact-us$` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us/contact-us/$` without luck.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: The right way of using it is this one: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us/contact-us/$`. This should work as expected, there must be another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that the way I had tried it (`!^/about-us/contact-us$`) WAS correct, but the WordPress generated .htaccess rules for permalinks were either stopping it working, or overriding it. So thanks to Justing and zx81 for confirming that the general method was correct.

For anyone else facing this problem, the following rules will be added by Wordpress (at time of writing on WordPress v3.*) when permalinks are enabled:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

That 'L' designating the LAST rule breaks any further matching.

What I have now is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=4.3.2.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us/contact-us/$
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

...and it works as planned. Of course this will be overwritten whenever the permalink settings are saved or changed in WP admin :/

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your rule on the file name is too specific. If you relax it a bit, it should work. I made a few other esthetic tweaks.

Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^4.3.2.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !about-us/contact-us
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```